# Python command not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, python, 18.04

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 and it seems  the command

```
python <filename>.py
```

does nothing. It runs *.pyc files, it opens python if used as a shell.
Python2.7 and 3 has been installed.

I'm not sure what's wrong here. 
My guess it maybe the Path or the default python is messed up.

Update:

1> If I open VScode and I create a file in a folder with .py extension e.g. test.py
it never runs either from the terminal or the integrated terminal.

2> If I right click it and I click on "Run Python File in Terminal", it runs. And after I do this I can also call it from the integrated terminal.
using python test.py and it gives me the output.

Now the question is why is VScode behaving such? Why is it not identifying the python file created? Or is there a table where all python files are listed? As a file created in the integrated terminal will not work from the Bash either.

Comment: Really does nothing? No error message. That is strange -- unless the python file you're trying to run doesn't do anything. Are you sure it's going to do what you think it's going to do?

Comment: Are you literally typing `python <filename>.py` (including the angle brackets)?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of a script that doesn't work ?

Comment: How did you install Python 2.7?

Comment: my exact steps:
1> Created a file from vscode test.py
2> It has just 1 statement " print("HERE")
3> I run it from the integrated terminal and linux terminal using the following command "python test.py"
4> There is no output :X

It works perfectly in ubuntu 16.04 but not in 18.04

Comment: @steeldriver no I am obviously not doing that. I am just running the test file I created using "python test.py".

Comment: @muru

I installed python2.7 using "apt-get install python2.7"

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.6.5-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

 sudo apt-get install python2.7

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python2.7 is already the newest version (2.7.15~rc1-1).
python2.7 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

Comment: @Pandeyji not "obvious" at all - in fact, if you have a file called `filename` in the current directory that contains valid python (including an empty file), then `python <filename>.py` would do exactly what you described (silently executing the commands in `filename` and redirecting its output to a hidden file called `.py`) - **that's** why I asked you to clarify

Comment: Did you install `python-minimal` as well?

Comment: @steeldriver I understand. But any idea why it's not working?

Comment: @muru no I haven't , should I ?

Comment: @Pandeyji I doubt anyone will be able to guess unless you [edit] your question to include a minimal testable example

Comment: @steeldriver I Just updated my question. I did a little more testing and found few things.

Comment: Try ignoring VSCode for the moment, and manually create a .py file that just contains `print('HERE')`, and try running that.

Comment: You could also check the file's **size** before and after running it from VScode - perhaps it is initially created as an empty file, and the content only gets written when you "Run Python File in Terminal"?

Comment: @wjandrea after updating my python it seems that it is working from outside VScode. I tried the same from the terminal -> Nano . But it still doesn't run if I create a file from VScode

Comment: @steeldriver you were right. It was 0kb even with the code. I enabled autosave and tested again and it worked !! Seems like I had got so used to autosave that I probably wasn't saving it. It was my mistake.
Thank you so much and sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As surmised by steeldriver in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) and confirmed by Pandeyji in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047761/python-command-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04#comment1711120_1047761) vscode is creating the file but not actually writing it's content until it  was either run in the virtual terminal or saved manually. [Manually saving or turning on autosave](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save) resolves the problem.

Sources:

Comments linked to in answer and

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Python 3 by default. If you installed python 2.7 you need to execute the file in the version you want to run. So in the terminal change to the directory where the .py file is you're trying to run and use either $ python filename.py for python 2 or 
$ python3 filename.py to execute a python 3 file.

Comment: But it should work either ways right? Also I have tried using 
python2.7 test.py
python3 test.py

both...but none works

Comment: python(3) is installed but when i type python --version it sais python not found.

Comment: editing /etc/environment and adding a pointer to /usr/bin/python which was just a symbolic link i'd made to python3.6m of that same dir, did the trick for me